# При парсинге сайта возможно ли нажать на кнопку на сайте без Webdriver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautiful-soup

Изучаю python, написал не большой парсер авито, и чтоб получить телефон на данном этапе я вызываю webdriver и с помощью selenium нажимаю на кнопку, чтоб появилась модалка с телефоном, далее получаю телефон BeautifulSoup и распознаю, но меня интересует, возможно ли как-нибудь без webdriver нажать на кнопку, т.е. не открывая браузер?

[image: Кнопка которую нужно нажать]

Comment: Конечно, возможно. В итоге Вы отправляете какой-то запрос, нужно лишь понять, как он формируется, и отправить его. Но это крайне сложно. Потребуется изучить `JavaScript` на странице, т. е. провести реверс-инжиниринг. На крупных сайтах алгоритмы специально усложняют и запутывают, чтобы затянуть этот процесс. Можете попробовать разобраться, но без должной подготовки у Вас навряд ли что-то получится.

Comment: А чем его передать если я нашёл?

Comment: Может помочь модуль `requests`. Пример запроса: `requests.get('https://example.edu', headers={})`.

Comment: Давно интереса ради делал парсер телефонов с авито: https://github.com/gil9red/ads_sites_parser/tree/cc3544cb9d167d425f36c880fc0c41dcdb020972/avito_ru_phone_parser Но потом узнал, что можно вместо парсинга картинки с номером телефона можно получить в виде текста из мобильной версии сайта. А так... откройте инспектор браузера (F12) и на вкладке Сети смотрите на запросы, особенно то, какие запросы уходят при клике на ту кнопку и повторите этот запрос